# Not able to add subview to my UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subclass, subview

I have a `UIView` element on the screen. It is connected by an `IBOutlet` `radioButtonGroupView`. I am trying to add a subview to that element and it is not working. The subview is never added.

Here is my code:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];


    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.radioButtonGroupView addSubview:subView];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Because my UITableView is contained in a nib file. The initWithCoder method does get called but the subview is never added.

Comment: `radioButtonGroupView` would be nil at this time.

Comment: So, I think I should do that in the view controller?

Comment: move these lines to `viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear:` and it will work..

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be better off if you make this element a subclass of a `UIViewController` (instead of a `UIView`).

Then put the subview loading code inside `viewDidLoad` method.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad]; //not really needed but it doesn't hurt

        UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        [self.radioButtonGroupView addSubview:subView];
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You say that you don't get any frame information on `self.radioButtonGroupView` in your `viewDidLoad`. That is almost a certain sign that your `IBOutlet` is not properly connected to the element in InterfaceBuilder. You can always make a simple test:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; //not really needed but it doesn't hurt

    NSLog (@"self.radioButtonGroupView: %@",self.radioButtonGroupView);

    [self.radioButtonGroupView setHidden:YES];
}
```

If it is still shown - then it simply isn't properly connected. IB has it's ways. Simple
deletion of `IBOutlet` connection and reconnecting it again might do the trick. Also: it your `radioButtonGroupView` is not `UIView` but a subclass of `UIView`, make sure that it's header file is imported in your `MyViewController.m` file and class properly defined in `.xib`.

Comment: If I use it in a view controller then self.radioButtonGroupView.frame.origin.x and y and width & height everything returns 0.

Comment: Most probably a connection to IB Outlet is missing or misplaced.

Comment: It is connected! I always have this problem that in my view controllers I cannot get the current coordinates for the IB elements.

Comment: Check, if self.radioButtonGroupView is nil at that time (viewDidLoad).